# SharePoint Distributed Cache Configuration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, performance, distributedcache

I have a SharePoint Farm with 2 WFEs but not for load balancing, rather for fail over if one WFE is down. the 5 is the main, 4 is the 2nd WFE, and here's the distributed cache configuration:
[image]

Is it normal that IsLeadHost is true for both, and why are the versions different?

Also, is this a cluster or not really? As I want to know how to restart/reprovision them as well

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not use `IsLeadHost` but rather the Configuration database defines this -- there is essentially no lead host. With that said, both FEs will have active cache fractions. You cannot have a passive DC host.

With that said, it also makes little sense to have an FE for 'failover' purposes. In SharePoint 2013, requests may be sent to the FE you do not have in the load balancer configuration as the internal SharePoint topology manager isn't 'smart'. This changed with SharePoint 2016 where SharePoint will do it's best to serve the end user on the same FE they arrived on -- this does require a [streamlined topology](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37000) (using MinRole in 2016 accomplishes this) where by many end user service instances run on the FE, such as MMS, UPS, and more.

Comment: this article says there should only be one lead host: https://www.spjeff.com/2018/11/08/fixed-distributed-cache-is-unhappy/ and also the highlighted different versions in my screenshot make me wonder if my distributed cache is healthy. please advise

Comment: Looks like you do have different patch levels for DistCache. I'd suggest checking your AppFab patches in Add/Remove Programs. Though you do have a fundamental architectural issue with your farm that you should resolve.

Comment: Can you let me know how to check for such fundamental issues

Comment: As stated in my post, follow the streamlined topology configuration and note there is no such thing as a "failover" FE. All SharePoint servers in a farm are active nodes.

Comment: i would need more help analysing my current set up and how to fix it. can you help?

Comment: First thing you should do is remove DC from the server showing version 0. From there, examine the patch levels you've applied to the server showing version 3. Once you install those same patches on the server you removed, re-add that server you removed. `IsLeadHost` is expected behavior on all DC members. From there, I would then follow the streamlined doc I linked earlier and move that FE into rotation since there is no concept of 'failover' FEs.